# Same values for viewmodel and model constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-fluent-api

I am developping a .net core app with 4 projects

- core (where models are defined)
- infrastructure (contains migrations and fluent api for core entities)
- app (business logic)
- web (razor pages and viewmodels)

I am defining model constraints with fluent API in order to keep my model clean and isolated from database aspects. No data annotation is used in core library.

What I would like to achive is defining **constraints** (lets say a string property length) that are **shared** between the fluent api configuration and related viewmodels.

Class with Constraints defined as constants

```
    namespace Infrastructure.Data.FluentApiConfiguration
    {
            public class ModelConfigurationConstants
            {
                public const int CODE_MAX_LENGTH = 10;
        
            }
        }
```

Fluent Api Configuration

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.FluentApiConfiguration
{
    class TipoBaseConfiguration<T> : EntityConfiguration<T> where T : TipoBase
        {
    
            public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
            {
                base.Configure(builder);
                builder.Property(x => x.Code)
                    .HasMaxLength(ModelConfigurationConstants.CODE_MAX_LENGTH)
                    .IsRequired();
            }
        }
}
```

ViewModel, with constraints as data annotation.

```
    namespace Web.ViewModels.Tipos
    {
        public class TipoBaseViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            [MaxLength(ModelConfigurationConstants.CODE_MAX_LENGTH)]
            public string Code{ get; set; }
    
        }
    }
```

Is this the most appropiate way to do this? Is there other way to have viewmodels that translate to models with equivalent validations (Required, maxlength, email formatting...).?

Comment: Hi @JMC, you can also try to store the value in appSettings.json and use IConfiguration to get the value.

Comment: Thank you for your replly. I think that approach could lead to the idea that constraints are something that can be "configured" once deployed. But changing the max length of a string should be followed by a migration in order to update the model. That's why I prefer to have hardcoded my constraints (avoid external changes without code updates). The point I am trying to solve is how to apply DRY and define only once that constraints.